# Using more than one javascript function for the same form

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-group

I have a table in which there is a radio group. There are 5 items and each item has 4 choices (the values for which are 0, 1, 2, 3). I need to not only calculate the total of all these, but also the number of Fails (value = 0). I have work js for both of these. How can I use these together? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Count Fails (value = 0):

```js
function setRadios() {
    function countFail() {
        var numFail = 0;
        oForm = this.form;

        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            var radgrp = document.getElementsByName('Set' + i);
            for (var j = 0; j < radgrp.length; j++) {
                var radio = radgrp[j];
                if (radio.value == "0" && radio.checked) {
                    numFail++;
                }
            }
        }

        oForm.elements.numFail.value = numFail;
    }

    var i = 0,
        input, inputs = document.getElementById('f1').getElementsByTagName('input');

    while (input = inputs.item(i++))
        input.onclick = countFail;
}

onload = setRadios;
```

Total:

```js
function setRadios() {
    function sumRadios() {
        var total = 0,
            i = 1,
            oForm = this.form;

        while (radgrp = oForm.elements['Set' + (i++)]) {
            j = radgrp.length;
            do
                if (radgrp[--j].checked) {
                    total += Number(radgrp[j].value);
                    break;
                }
            while (j);
        }

        oForm.elements.total.value = total;
    }

    var i = 0,
        input, inputs = document.getElementById('f1').getElementsByTagName('input');

    while (input = inputs.item(i++))
        input.onclick = sumRadios;
}

onload = setRadios;
```

And finally here is the form (radio group) - set up to calculate the number of fails:

```html
<form method="post" id="f1" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
  <br>
  <form name="f1" method="post" name="buttons" id="f1" onsubmit="return false">
    <table width="75%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table_rs">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="20%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Extended Writing</td>
          <td width="20%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Fail</td>
          <td width="20%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Pass</td>
          <td width="20%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Merit</td>
          <td width="20%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Distinction</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="20%" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Task</td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="task1" type="radio" name="Set1" value="0" required/></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="task2" type="radio" name="Set1" value="1" /></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="task3" type="radio" name="Set1" value="2" /></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="task4" type="radio" name="Set1" value="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="20%" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Cohesion</td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="cohesion1" type="radio" name="Set2" value="0" required/></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="cohesion2" type="radio" name="Set2" value="1" /></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="cohesion3" type="radio" name="Set2" value="2" /></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="cohesion4" type="radio" name="Set2" value="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="20%" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Lexis</td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="lexis2" type="radio" name="Set3" value="0" required/></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="lexis3" type="radio" name="Set3" value="1" required/></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="lexis4" type="radio" name="Set3" value="2" /></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="lexis" type="radio" name="Set3" value="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Grammar</td>
          <td align="center"><input id="grammar2" type="radio" name="Set4" value="0" required/></td>
          <td align="center"><input id="grammar3" type="radio" name="Set4" value="1" /></td>
          <td align="center"><input id="grammar4" type="radio" name="Set4" value="2" /></td>
          <td align="center"><input id="grammar" type="radio" name="Set4" value="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="17%" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Sources</td>
          <td width="15%" align="center"><input id="sources1" type="radio" name="Set5" value="0" required/></td>
          <td width="17%" align="center"><input id="sources2" type="radio" name="Set5" value="1" /></td>
          <td width="17%" align="center"><input id="sources3" type="radio" name="Set4" value="2" /></td>
          <td width="17%" align="center"><input id="sources4" type="radio" name="Set4" value="3" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <div align="center">numFails: <input id="numFail" type="text" name="" value="" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: your code snippets do not run...

Comment: Can you simplify the code? This is hard to process.

Comment: I can assure you that the code does work even if the snippets do not. It might just be the way that I added them here.

Comment: I am OK with php but am a little new to javascript. I cannot simplify what I have, I wished that I could. I need to use js as I cannot do these calculations on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is the goods. Thank you so much. I did get it in the end without looking at your code (yours is MUCH better and way more elegant). I would love to hear what you think of my solution (it may not run as snippet, but it does run on my localhost). It is so gratifying when someone understands exactly what you are after.

```js
<?php
$currentPage = $_SERVER[ "PHP_SELF" ];
?>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <title>Basic Report</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function setRadios() {
   function countTotals() {
    var numFail = 0;
    var total = 0;
    oForm = this.form;
    for ( var i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) {
     var radgrp = document.getElementsByName( 'Set' + i );
     var radgrp1 = document.getElementsByName( 'Set' + i );
     
     for ( var j = 0; j < 5; j++ ) {
      var radio = radgrp[ j ];
      if ( radio.value == "0" && radio.checked ) {
       numFail++;
      }
      var radio1 = radgrp1[ j ];
      if ( radio1.checked ) {
       total += Number( radio.value );
      }
     }
    }
    oForm.elements.numFail.value = numFail;
    oForm.elements.total.value = total;
   }
   var i = 0,
    input, inputs = document.getElementById( 'f1' ).getElementsByTagName( 'input' );
   while ( input = inputs.item( i++ ) )
    input.onclick = countTotals;
    
  }
  onload = setRadios;
 </script>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" id="f1" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
<br>
<table width="75%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table_rs">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="17%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Extended Writing</td>
<td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Fail</td>
<td width="17%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Pass</td>
<td width="17%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Merit</td>
<td width="17%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Distinction</td>
<td width="17%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Excellence</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="17%" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Task</td>
<td width="15%" align="center"><input id="task1" type="radio" name="Set1" value="0" required/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="task2" type="radio" name="Set1" value="1"/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="task3" type="radio" name="Set1" value="2"/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="task4" type="radio" name="Set1" value="3"/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="task5" type="radio" name="Set1" value="4"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="17%" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Cohesion</td>
<td width="15%" align="center"><input id="cohesion1" type="radio" name="Set2" value="0" required/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="cohesion2" type="radio" name="Set2" value="1"/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="cohesion3" type="radio" name="Set2" value="2"/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="cohesion4" type="radio" name="Set2" value="3"/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="cohesion5" type="radio" name="Set2" value="4"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="17%" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Lexis</td>
<td width="15%" align="center"><input id="lexis1" type="radio" name="Set3" value="0" required/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="lexis2" type="radio" name="Set3" value="1"/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="lexis3" type="radio" name="Set3" value="2"/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="lexis4" type="radio" name="Set3" value="3"/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="lexis4" type="radio" name="Set3" value="4"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="17%" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Grammar</td>
<td width="15%" align="center"><input id="grammar1" type="radio" name="Set4" value="0" required/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="grammar2" type="radio" name="Set4" value="1"/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="grammar3" type="radio" name="Set4" value="2"/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="grammar4" type="radio" name="Set4" value="3"/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="grammar5" type="radio" name="Set4" value="4"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="17%" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Sources</td>
<td width="15%" align="center"><input id="sources1" type="radio" name="Set5" value="0" required/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="sources2" type="radio" name="Set5" value="1"/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="sources3" type="radio" name="Set5" value="2"/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="sources4" type="radio" name="Set5" value="3"/></td>
<td width="17%" align="center"><input id="grammar5" type="radio" name="Set5" value="4"/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<div align="center">NumFail: <input id="numFail" type="text" name="numFail" value=""/>
<div align="center">Total: <input id="total" type="text" name="total" value=""/>
<input type="reset" class="button1"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do it. The first one is to add multiple event handlers to one form. Simply:

```
document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('submit', sendForm);
document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('submit', clearForm);
```

The second one is to create an anonymous function and call these 2 functions inside it.

```
document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
  sendForm(event);
  clearForm(event);
});
```

Comment: The sumRadios function and countFail functions are both inside the setRadios function. The setRadios function is called (is that the right word?) when the radio buttons are clicked. I would like to output total (from sumRadios and countFail) separately through <input id="total" type="text" name="total" value=""/> and <input id="numFails" type="text" name="numFails" value=""/>. Please excuse my ignorance of these matters.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily put them together like i did here:

```js
function setRadios() {

  var i = 0,
    k = 0,
    input, inputs = document.getElementById('f1').getElementsByTagName('input');

  while (input = inputs.item(i++))
    input.onclick = countFail;

}

function countFail() {
  var numFail = 0;
  oForm = this.form;

  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var radgrp = document.getElementsByName('Set' + i);
    for (var j = 0; j < radgrp.length; j++) {
      var radio = radgrp[j];
      if (radio.value == "0" && radio.checked) {
        numFail++;
      }
    }
  }

  oForm.elements.numFail.value = numFail;
  sumRadios(oForm)
}

function sumRadios(oForm) {
  var total = 0,
    i = 1;

  while (radgrp = oForm.elements['Set' + (i++)]) {
    j = radgrp.length;
    do
      if (radgrp[--j].checked) {
        total += Number(radgrp[j].value);
        break;
      }
    while (j);
  }

  oForm.elements.total.value = total;
}

onload = setRadios;
```

```html
<form method="post" id="f1" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
  <br>
  <form name="f1" method="post" name="buttons" id="f1" onsubmit="return false">
    <table width="75%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table_rs">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="20%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Extended Writing</td>
          <td width="20%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Fail</td>
          <td width="20%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Pass</td>
          <td width="20%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Merit</td>
          <td width="20%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Distinction</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="20%" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Task</td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="task1" type="radio" name="Set1" value="0" required/></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="task2" type="radio" name="Set1" value="1" /></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="task3" type="radio" name="Set1" value="2" /></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="task4" type="radio" name="Set1" value="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="20%" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Cohesion</td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="cohesion1" type="radio" name="Set2" value="0" required/></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="cohesion2" type="radio" name="Set2" value="1" /></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="cohesion3" type="radio" name="Set2" value="2" /></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="cohesion4" type="radio" name="Set2" value="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="20%" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Lexis</td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="lexis2" type="radio" name="Set3" value="0" required/></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="lexis3" type="radio" name="Set3" value="1" required/></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="lexis4" type="radio" name="Set3" value="2" /></td>
          <td width="20%" align="center"><input id="lexis" type="radio" name="Set3" value="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Grammar</td>
          <td align="center"><input id="grammar2" type="radio" name="Set4" value="0" required/></td>
          <td align="center"><input id="grammar3" type="radio" name="Set4" value="1" /></td>
          <td align="center"><input id="grammar4" type="radio" name="Set4" value="2" /></td>
          <td align="center"><input id="grammar" type="radio" name="Set4" value="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="17%" bgcolor="#CCFFFF">Sources</td>
          <td width="15%" align="center"><input id="sources1" type="radio" name="Set5" value="0" required/></td>
          <td width="17%" align="center"><input id="sources2" type="radio" name="Set5" value="1" /></td>
          <td width="17%" align="center"><input id="sources3" type="radio" name="Set4" value="2" /></td>
          <td width="17%" align="center"><input id="sources4" type="radio" name="Set4" value="3" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <div align="center">numFails: <input id="numFail" type="text" name="" value="" />
      <div align="center">total: <input id="total" type="text" name="" value="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</form>
```